# Listbox value from userform intermittently not updating a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform in Excel. On loading, the form pulls data from the last row of a spreadsheet. There is a button on the form to print the form.

Prior to printing the form, it updates the selection in a list box for work order status to "Assigned" and then copies this status to the spreadsheet.

Sometimes the work order status in the spreadsheet is updated to "". It is like the selection of the list box is not being recognized. It is intermittent and I have not been able to determine a pattern.

This is the code

```
PrintWOForm.LB_WOStatus.value = "Assigned" 'Updates WO status to Assigned
```

To write this to the spreadsheet I have this code

```
'Update WO Status to Complete if there is a date in Date Completed
'Else update Status based on Selection in WO Status list box

If PrintWOForm.TB_DateComplete = "" Then
    ws.Cells(cRow, 4) = PrintWOForm.LB_WOStatus.value
Else
    ws.Cells(cRow, 4) = "Complete"
    ws.Cells(cRow, 23) = PrintWOForm.LB_RepairCode.value
End If
```

It appears when I first open the form and use the print button, which updates the selection in the list box LB_WOStatus to "Assigned", it copies a blank into cRow 4.

If I manually select a status in the list box, that time and every time forward it will work correctly even when the status is selected by the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is best the fix for my issue, but so far it appears to work well. I added the below first line of code in front the prexesting second line of code.

```
Me.LB_WOStatus.SetFocus 'Must SetFocus to the WOStatus list box for the application to realize the next line of code
Me.LB_WOStatus.value = "Assigned" 'Updates WO status to Assigned
```

I did not try using the SetFocus method previously because I read on one of these websites that this was only used to set the focus to the object for the user of the form.